# Какие были реальные ситуации в которых приходилось использовать immutable collections?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

В .NET есть System.Collections.Immutable. Был реальный опыт использования, который того стоил?

Comment: "какие были реальные ситуации, в которых приходилось использовать properties?", "какие были реальные ситуации, в которых приходилось использовать паттерны проектирования?", "какие были реальные ситуации, в которых приходилось использовать DI?" и т.д. Т.е. зачем использовать интерфейсы, когда есть классы; зачем использовать св-ва, когда есть поля; зачем использовать неизменяемые коллекции, когда есть изменяемые. в официальной документации, по-моему, всё понятно расписано.

Comment: Да, был. Можно ли меня теперь считать мужчиной?

Comment: Хотите, подскажу, какая немутабельная коллекция у вас всегда под носом, вы ее постоянно используете и не видите? (шок контент 18+)

Comment: return, тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-5.0 ? Я постоянно использую классы/интерфейсы и поля/свойства, тут я уже привык. Но ситуаций когда я буду испльзвать immutable не придумаю сходу, разве что если будут коммитить совсем не разбираясь в китически важную логику связанную с коллекциями.

Comment: aepot, string ?

Comment: @John именно так. Но вторую немутабельную коллекцию вы вряд-ли уже назовете. :)

Comment: @aepot То, что строки немутабельны - дело известное, но в явном виде от `System.Collections.Immutable` они не унаследованы, так что это не совсем про то )  Но как пример использования иммутабельности - вариант, конечно

Comment: Что значит того стоил? Это как с уровнями доступа к членам класса, например, по умолчанию надо выбирать наиболее защищённый (private) и повышать только в случае необходимости. Так же и с коллекциями, по хорошему, надо выбирать мутабельную коллекцию только когда вам эта мутабельность явно нужна. Но с коллекциями несколько все сложнее по историческим причинам — эти иммутабельные коллекции появились достаточно недавно + не сразу вошли в состав BCL + несколько непривычный API и т.д.

Comment: Я думаю, что если бы BCL разрабатывалась сейчас заново, то иерархия классов/интерфейсов коллекций была бы несколько другой, может даже кардинально

Comment: _если бы BCL разрабатывалась ... заново, то ... была бы ... другой_ - несомненно. В книге Framework Design Guidelines (3-е издание, 2020) есть примеры грубых просчётов и того, как авторы сделали бы сейчас.

Comment: Иммутабельные типы (как коллекции, так и сущности) активно используются в многопоточном коде при программировании в функциональном стиле.

Answer (score 3):

Реальный и основной метод использования

System.Collections.Immutable у меня это многопоточность. У вас есть список и если хотите его обезопасить, то имутабельность вас оградит от проблем, которые может создать мутации во многих потоках.

Прошу не холиварить. Я лишь указываю что имутабельность может оградить от проблем. При этом если вам нужно чтоб объект мутировал для этого существует другие механизмы.

Comment: А какой тут может быть холивар? Для многопоточных сценариев immutability наше всё.